# VB.NET OLEDBDataReader - Null value in resultset (DATETIME)

Tags: oracle, datetime, null, oledbdatareader

I'm new to VB.NET programming, so pointing to examples is greatly appreciated.

I've got a OleDB connection to an Oracle 11g database.  I'm reading a single row from a table and trying to populate a row object (mClockInOutInfo).  The problem I'm running into is that there is a null DateTime (timestamp) column in the returned row.

Of course, I started with the mClockInOutInfo.RowDate = dr.GetDateTime(0) (assume the RowDate column is the first column in the query).

I quickly found out that nulls should be checked, so I added the = If(IsDBNull(dr.GetDateTime(0)), DBNull.value, dr.getDateTime(0)) to the code.  (I now use the NullSafeString functions found around here somewhere. But there was nothing for DateTime types.  I tried to make one, no success.   So I'm still with the If(IsDbNull(...)) code for my datetime columns.

The problem I'm having is that I get the error: "Specified cast is not valid." when evaluating that statement.  I've verified the column type with the .GetDataTypeName(0) method. It returns DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP.  I've reviewed the schema information to verify that the column is actually the information I'm looking for.  From what I can tell, the error is being generated while evaluating the IsDBNull(drRecent.GetDateTime(0)) portion of the if() statement.  I've confirmed this by breaking the statement into a multi-line if statement:
if IsDBNull(dr.GetDateTime(0)) Then
...
Else
...
End If

I get the same cast error thrown by the if IsDBNull(...) line.

So, I went back to the SQL string and did a Coalesce on the column with the empty data in it.  I received the same cast error. Finally, frustrated, I changed the sql query to use the TO_DATE function and fed in a date string with the appropriate format parameter.  I STILL receive this same cast error.

The property in the mClockInOutInfo is defined as DateTime.  There are other columns defined exactly the same way and those that have data in the table are not giving any errors.

Any ideas of what I should be doing when the database allows nulls in a DateTime (Timestamp) column?  All ideas welcomed.  Thank you in advance.